# JSON returns urls twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an html table on a page with raws that have 'urls', I'm trying to fetch one url at a time from a random row, however my code returns url as http://www.test.com/products/product-namehttp://www.test.com/products/product-name.json, as you can see it returns url twice, one without json and other with json data, hence I'm getting 404.

I just need the .json URL, not the first part.

How do I get rid of the first url which is not json?

Here's the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#closepopup', function() {
    $("#popup").removeClass('popupslidein')
  });
  var tablelink = "https://test.com/pages/product-listing-for-popups.json"; //products url for json data
  $.getJSON(tablelink, function(data) {
    var table = data.page.body_html;
    $('#popuptable').append(table);
    startthepopups()
  });
  var suburbink = "https://test.com/pages/product-listing-suburbs-for-popups"; //suburb names in table rows
  $.getJSON(suburbink, function(data) {
    var suburb = data.page.body_html;
    $('#popupsuburb').append(suburb)
  });
  var namelink = "https://test.com/pages/product-listing-names-for-popups"; //names in table rows
  $.getJSON(namelink, function(data) {
    var name = data.page.body_html;
    $('#popupname').append(name)
  });

  function startthepopups() {
    var popupstay = 10000;
    var popuptrigger = 100000;

    function triggerpopup() {
      var getrandomtd = Math.floor((Math.random() * $('#popuptable tr').length) + 1);
      var link = $('#popuptable tr:nth-child(' + getrandomtd + ')').text();
      console.log(link);
      var productname = '';
      var getrandomsuburbtd = Math.floor((Math.random() * $('#popupsuburb tr').length) + 1);
      var suburblink = $('#popupsuburb tr:nth-child(' + getrandomsuburbtd + ')').text();
      var getrandomnametd = Math.floor((Math.random() * $('#popupname tr').length) + 1);
      var randomname = $('#popupname tr:nth-child(' + getrandomnametd + ')').text();
      $.getJSON(link + '.json', function(data) {
        productname = data.product.title;
        imagelink = data.product.images[0].src;
        if (!$("#popup").hasClass("popupslidein")) {
          $('#popupsomeone span.name').empty().append(randomname);
          $('#popupsomeone span.location').empty().append(suburblink);
          $('#popupimage').css('background-image', 'url(' + imagelink.split('.jpg')[0] + '_small.jpg)');
          $('#popupproduct a').attr('href', link).empty().append(productname);
          $("#popupagotext").empty().append(Math.round(Math.random() * 15 + 10));
          $("#popup").addClass('popupslidein');
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#popup").removeClass('popupslidein')
          }, popupstay);
        }
      });
    }(function loop() {
      var random = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) * 100000 + popuptrigger;
      setTimeout(function() {
        triggerpopup();
        loop()
      }, 60000)
    }());
  }

});
```

Comment: Getting whole row text is unusual as opposed to targeting a cell's text. Using `nth-child` it is also possible that more than one row is included in collection depending on structure of table. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the link

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON()` has a tendency to append your current url to the path you pass it if it thinks it's relative. To make this work, you could try to use `$.getJSON()` like so. Keep in mind, the protocol used will be the current page this code lives on.

```
$.getJSON('//test.com/pages/product-listing-for-popups.json')
```

I also noticed that nowhere in your code do you have a url for `http://www.test.com/products/product-name.json`, are you sure you're sharing the correct snippet of code?

#### Working Demo

The following two ways of using `$.getJSON()` with a fully qualified url work perfectly fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1";
  
  // Example 1
  $.getJSON(url)
    .done(function( data ) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    
  // Example 2
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: To add to this answer -- the `//` prepending the url will match the current protocol of your page. (Either `http` or `https`).

Comment: Hi @AnonymousSB,  Thanks for your answer however it didn't fix the issue. Regarding -> "I also noticed that nowhere in your code do you have a url", as you can see in the code, 'link' variable builds this url using 'url' value is in the table row at https://test.com/pages/product-listing-for-popups.json

Comment: @shutupchigo Can you provide what the result of `data.page.body_html` is? What is the output of your `console.log(link)` line?